# Getting all materials attached to object throughout all render layers [Maya]

Tags: python, python-2.7, maya

**Issue**

Getting all materials attached to an object without switching render layers; getting the materials from other render layers for the particular object.

**Code to get material from object**

```
# Gets all shaders attached to the current renderLayer for all objects in "group1"
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.select("group1")
allChildren = cmds.listRelatives(ad=1)
for eachChild in allChildren:
    # Get the shader groups attached to this particular object
    shaderGroups = cmds.listConnections(cmds.listHistory(eachChild))
    if shaderGroups is not None:
        # Get the material attached to the shader group
        materials = [x for x in cmds.ls(cmds.listConnections(shaderGroups), materials=1)]
print materials
```

The only other way I know to get information for the placed in other render layers is to switch to them and then run the same code... Anyone have any other suggestions?

*Edit:*

`cmds.listConnections()` and `cmds.listHistory()` and the combination of the two above seem to provide the render layers, themselves, if attached to the objects that I'm getting materials from; I.E. - `materials = [u'Car_Paint_Material', u'RenderLayer_BluePaint', u'RenderLayer_RedPaint']`.

*Edit #2:*

Screenshots!

[image: defaultRenderLayer -> Red material for selected object]
defaultRenderLayer -> Red material for selected object.

[image: layer1 -> Green material for selected object]
layer1             -> Green material for selected object.

[image: Run above script to get material]
Run above script to get material.

[image: Run un-optimized to get object + renderLayer + material]
Run un-optimized to get object + renderLayer + material.
It works, but it has to switch render layers to get that information.

I need a solution that gets the above information without switching renderlayers.

Comment: you have added an answer below. So has the problem been resolved now?

Comment: No, @Kaveen Perera. It's the only way I know right now and it's definitely not what I'm looking for. I need the script to get the objects materials for all render layers from the default one. Currently, I have to switch between each render layer to get the materials and it's highly unoptimized.

Comment: See my answer below. It does the job :)

Comment: @KaveenPerera, it's not exactly what I need but it's so close I can work with it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks James. Could you clarify the exact requirement like the returning format of the information etc so I can certainly look into that.

Comment: Well, I shouldn't have you do all the work. ;) Basically, I noticed it returns the material for certain objects but not all of them. Most of the time, it returned `{"object1": {}}`. Object1 being whatever model is in my scene.

Comment: That happens when no material is attached to the object. you can remove the if condition on line 19 and check. the reason I added that was, when i deleted some objects the connection is still preserves by Maya but the content was null. try and let me know.

Comment: if an object doesn't have a new shader applied in a render layer other than the default render layer, the script outputs an empty dict fir the object in interest. If you at lease have a new shader in one render layer then it will only output the shader details for the available render layers. Just re tested the code. Hope I explained it clearly.

Comment: That's a bit strange, as I do have shaders / materials attached to all objects in my scene - the file I'm using it on is a bit proprietary so I can't post it.

Comment: I'll give it another test soon.

Comment: Confirmed that it doesn't work the way I need it to (strange that it's working for you and not me). However, it's one giant leap towards what I need. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problem in your approach

`materials = [x for x in cmds.ls(cmds.listConnections(shaderGroups), materials=1)]` only returns the shader name of the selected layer.

#### Solution

Following script will store all the materials from all the models of all the layers in a dictionary in the following order;

`meshName : {layerName : shader/MaterialName}`

It is stored in a dictionary called `objectList`

The script was tested with a scene with 1203 objects and 2 render layers (+the default render layer). It executes in a fraction of a second.

```
meshList = cmds.ls(type='mesh')
shaderList = {}
for mesh in meshList:
    shaderList[mesh]={}

#get render layers
renderLayers = [x for x in cmds.ls(type="renderLayer")]

for eachLayer in renderLayers:
    currentRenderLayerName = eachLayer
    attrib = currentRenderLayerName+'.outAdjustments'
    numberOfConnectedMeshes = len(cmds.getAttr(attrib, multiIndices=True))

    for currentMeshIndex in range(numberOfConnectedMeshes):

        queryConnection = currentRenderLayerName + '.outAdjustments['+str(currentMeshIndex)+']'
        # sometimes if you delete an object, the connection might still be active.
        # validating it with an if condition avoids errors
        if cmds.listConnections(queryConnection+'.outPlug') !=  None:

            # following line should technically return a mesh name, however it returns the transform object name
            currentTransformObject = cmds.listConnections(queryConnection+'.outPlug')[0]
            # following line is important as the 'currentTransformObject' does is the not mesh name.
            # if it does return the mesh object then just change 'currentTransformObject' to 'currentMeshName'
            # and comment out the following line
            currentMeshName = cmds.listRelatives(currentTransformObject)[0]

            currentMeshShadingGroup = cmds.listConnections(queryConnection+'.outValue')[0]
            currentShadingGroupSurfaceShader = cmds.listConnections(currentMeshShadingGroup+'.surfaceShader')

            shaderList[currentMeshName][currentRenderLayerName] = currentShadingGroupSurfaceShader

# If you only have objects on the defaultRenderLayer
# above code ignored those objects.
# following will add them to the shaderList dict
for eachMesh in shaderList:
    if shaderList[eachMesh]=={}:
        currentRenderLayerName  = "defaultRenderLayer"
        materialAppliedToObject = cmds.ls(cmds.listConnections(cmds.listConnections(
                                          cmds.listHistory(cmds.listRelatives(eachMesh, parent=1)))), 
                                          mat=1)[0]
        shaderList[eachMesh][currentRenderLayerName] = materialAppliedToObject
```

this returned on the sample scene with three objects the following.

```
shaderList
# Result: 
{
    u'pSphereShape0':
        {
        u'defaultRenderLayer': [u'lambert2'],
        },
    u'pSphereShape1': 
        {
        u'defaultRenderLayer': [u'anisotropic1'], 
        u'layer2': [u'anisotropic3'], 
        u'layer1': [u'anisotropic2']
        }, 
    u'pCubeShape1':
        {
        u'defaultRenderLayer': [u'phong1'], 
        u'layer2': [u'phong3'], 
        u'layer1': [u'phong2']
        },
    u'pConeShape1':
        {
        u'defaultRenderLayer': [u'blinn1'], 
        u'layer2': [u'blinn3'], 
        u'layer1': [u'blinn2']
        }
} #
```

to query a surface shader of a given mesh to the corresponding layer use the following form

```
shaderList['pCubeShape1']['layer2']

# Result: [u'phong3'] 
# notice it returns a list.
# you have to use the index if you need only the name 
#`objectList['pCubeShape1']['layer2'][0]`
```

#### How to customise?

You can re arrange the order of the dict by directly editing the code, or a better alternative is you can query the shaders list of a selected object or a group of objects, and store that in a new variable in the desired order.

#### Important

If an object **is not added** to a render layer, a corresponding shader information will not be returned.

#### Tested with

Mental Ray / Software / Hardware 2.0 Renderers
(Please add to the answer if any of you have success with other rendereres)

Comment: For anyone looking for the answer as to why this *almost* works for me... I figured the problem out. If you've got models that don't appear in the renderlayers, they will come up blank in the dictionary. This script works perfectly! So, TL;DR : Make sure each of your objects are in each renderlayer.

Comment: @SirJames you can update the answer. I think its best to add that to the last *Important* section.

Comment: @SirJames what renderer do you use? I only tested this with Maya's built-in  software renderer. Just wondering if it works for other plugin renderers as well.

Comment: I'm only using Mental Ray / Software / Hardware 2.0 Renderers (all default pre-2017).

Comment: Cheers. I'll update on the answer as tested renderers

Comment: I think the reason it didn't detect objects added to the render layer was due in part by the groups above them being added and not the objects themselves. The added bit I threw in there is sure to make it work.

Comment: Just want to doubly state, Kaveen, this is an amazing answer. I'm still baffled by how you figured it out and impressed that it's so efficient. Thank you once again!

Comment: Cheers. Yes it should have. My test scene was very basic so one might needs customising the script to match the scene. Saving the Maya file as a .ma and examining mel code will help you in the future. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a temporary solution:

```
# Gets all shaders attached to the current renderLayer for all objects in "group1"
import maya.cmds as cmds

# Create a dictionary for {"object1": ["material1", "material2"]}
objectToMaterials = {}

# List of renderlayers
renderLayers = [x for x in cmds.ls(type="renderLayer")]

# Pick each renderLayer and switch to it


cmds.select("group1")
allChildren = cmds.listRelatives(ad=1)
for eachChild in allChildren:
    if cmds.objectType(eachChild)=="mesh":
        eachChild = cmds.listRelatives(eachChild, parent=1)
        for eachRenderLayer in renderLayers:
            cmds.editRenderLayerGlobals(crl=eachRenderLayer)
            # Get the shader groups attached to this particular object
            shaderGroups = cmds.listConnections(cmds.listHistory(eachChild))
            if shaderGroups is not None:
                # Get the material attached to the shader group
                materials = [x for x in cmds.ls(cmds.listConnections(shaderGroups), materials=1)]

            objectToMaterials.setdefault(eachChild[0], []).append(eachRenderLayer)
            objectToMaterials.setdefault(eachChild[0], []).append(materials[0])

print(objectToMaterials)

# objectToMaterials = {"object1": ["defaultRenderLayer", "RenderLayer_RedPaint"], ["secondRenderLayer", "RenderLayer_BluePaint"], "object2": ["defaultRenderLayer", "RenderLayer_BluePaint"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# we need a sandbox case   
collection = []
for layer in cmds.ls(type = "renderLayer"):
    members =  cmds.editRenderLayerMembers( layer, query=True)
    for i in members:
        shader_engine = cmds.listConnections(cmds.listHistory(i), type = 'shadingEngine')
        _shaders = cmds.ls(cmds.listConnections(shader_engine), materials= True)
    collection.append(dict(object = members, layer = layer, engine = shader_engine, shaders = _shaders))
print collection

[{'engine': [u'blinn2SG'], 'layer': u'defaultRenderLayer', 'object': [u'pSphere1', u'pSphereShape1', u'pSphere2', u'pSphereShape2'], 'shaders': [u'blinn2']}, {'engine': [u'lambert2SG'], 'layer': u'layer1', 'object': [u'pSphere1'], 'shaders': [u'lambert2']}, {'engine': [u'blinn2SG'], 'layer': u'layer2', 'object': [u'pSphere2'], 'shaders': [u'blinn2']}]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that provides the same result I have right now - I've got about 20-40 render layers and about 1000 models on screen. The result is that it takes forever to switch between render layers and I need a simpler, less invasive way of querying materials for each model.

Comment: The result is that Maya is switching between all the Render Layers and is hung up until it finishes jumping through hoops. -> Time is being wasted. I'll let it run for now to see how long it takes though.

Comment: i removed the line, timeit please

Comment: Tested... It is not getting the materials attached to the other render layers for all objects, for whatever reason. So, regardless of the layer or object, the material stays the same... It also doesn't do anything that is expect... It seems but it is grabbing new information, which is kind of cool.

Comment: i guess my test scene is not really well for the task, have you any test file for me.....?

Comment: I do not, at the moment. The easiest way to test is: create two cubes, create two render layers, add materials to both on defaultRenderLayer, then switch to the new renderLayer and add two new materials. Try and get both sets of materials without switching to a new renderLayer. Or I can post a scene in two hours.

Comment: Thx, post your Scene please

Comment: I didn't have the time last night to post up a scene... However, I will post screenshots today.